# What does "Eleventy-seven" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, colloquialisms, australian-english

I came across the following phrase in a story (set in Australia):

> So the fact that I'm forty-five and you're eleventy-seven means nothing to me. If other people have a problem with that, then it's their problem, not ours.

The character is obviously talking about age difference, but is "eleventy-seven" translate to an actual number? Or is it an Australian colloquialism for "really old"?

I tried to search for the phrase, but all I found were pages about a musical group of the same name :)

Comment: I'd like to see more of the context.  From what I gather it could be the 45 year old is with an 18 year old, but they are in denial to refer to the 18 year old as such.  I say this because of the second sentence. `If other people have a problem with that, then it's their problem, not ours.`

Comment: This reminds me of J.R.R. Tolkien's "twelvety" http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=twelvety And by that number system, it would mean "eleventy seven" was 117.

Comment: Best I can tell, the character is approximately retirement age, probably in his 60s? So she's definitely not being literal about him being 117 years old :). His reply to her was (I assume similarly joking) "Eleventy-seven was ten years ago."

Comment: If I remember right, there was a Calvin & Hobbes strip about math that involved "eleventy-seven". In any case, it's used as a nonsense number out of LotR context.

Comment: I would say it means: I'm 45 and you're much older than that.

Comment: Equivalent to "umpteen" -- an unspecified moderately large number.

Comment: As others have suggested, it's a humorous way of saying "You're much older than me" without being specific. If memory serves, in the 1970s BBC series of Wurzel Gummidge with John Pertwee as the eponymous hero, he referred to a coin as an "eleventy-twelve pence piece". Conversely, I was once asked for "a hundred and eleventeen pence" when buying a round of drinks (it was a long time ago!). When I raised a quizzical eyebrow, the landlord explained that he had counted up "a hundred and nineteen, a hundred and tenteen, a hundred and eleventeen". So, unusually, the number had a precise value.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's either a [real number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/110_%28number%29)

> 110, It is also known as "eleventy", a term made famous by linguist and author J. R. R. Tolkien (Bilbo Baggins celebrates his eleventy-first birthday at the beginning of The Lord of the Rings) and derived from the Old English hund endleofantig. When the word eleventy is used, it may indicate the exact number (110)

Therefore using extrapolation we can assume the author meant 117.

OR

an example of an [indefinite (or exagerated) number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_and_fictitious_numbers)

> inexact terms of indefinite size, used for comic effect, for exaggeration, as placeholder names, or when precision is unnecessary or undesirable.

Comment: Accepted for the link that includes other gems like *buckets, couple-few, "forty-leven", oodles, scads*, and (my personal favorite) a *metric load*. Not on the list, but I sometimes use a "*crap ton*" to mean a large amount, or perhaps a "*metric crap ton*".

Comment: @BradC: I suppose then, that _eleventy-seven_ could just be a much smaller version of _zillion_ or _gazillion_.

Answer (score 14):

In The Fellowship of the Ring, Bilbo Baggins was 111 years old and he called it "eleventy-one".

> “Today is my one hundred and eleventh birthday: I am eleventy-one today!”

So if the speaker is serious, it would make sense to infer eleventy-seven means 117. But since this is not a normal way of speaking about the number 117, and because people don't often reach 117 years old (or, if they do, it IS significant), it's hard to tell if the speaker literally means 117 or just means "some big number that is much higher than 45". You'll have to determine that from the rest of the story.

Comment: Yup: LotR is certainly where I learned this phrase. As far as I know, there is nothing regional about it - people all over the world use "eleventy-[number]" as a semi-humorous and semi-indeterminate large number.

Answer (score 8):

From [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=eleventy-seven):

> An imaginary number to be used when you have lost count of something
>   and you need to verbally state a quantity.

Comment: So is it a distinctly Australian phrase? Or is it also used in the UK? (I've never heard it used in the US.)

Comment: @BradC: This is the first time I've heard it, so I don't really know. :(

Comment: In AmE, it is used mostly by children as more of a repeated analogical neologism when counting by tens: seventy, eighty, ninety...eleventy. 'Twelvety' just doesn't sound right.

Comment: I have heard it before though not commonly in the US.

Comment: It's used quite commonly in the UK.

Comment: @Waggers, what region of the UK? I've never heard anyone use it. Is it a dialect thing?

Comment: I've heard it used in the US to express a decently large number in a humorous way--'decently large', in this context, would be considerably less than a gajillion.

Comment: @Andy F I live on the south coast and have heard it quite a bit - but that's not to say everyone in this neck of the woods would be familiar with it. I think it's more down to the field of work rather than geographical location - I've spent several years working in a mathematical/analytical field where we would talk about numbers quite a lot without always wanting to refer to a particular figure (and not wanting to say "x" all the time) - if you don't find yourself in that situation much you're less likely to come across the phrase

Answer (score 5):

In this case, the speaker is using *"eleventy-seven"* as an arbitrary number; the point is, the age-gap between the speakers is large, but he doesn't care.  He could have gotten the same effect by using a number much larger or smaller than her actual age:

> The fact that I'm forty-five and you're seven means nothing to me.
>
> The fact that I'm forty-five and you're 120 means nothing to me.

Using a made-up number adds a bit of sarcasm/humor, emphasizing the point that he doesn't care about her age.

---

I've heard *"eleventeen,"* "*threlve,*" and *"a zillion/dillion/gajillion"* used as humorous-sounding made-up numbers in similar contexts before.  *(A friend of mine always used to offer me "threlve doll-hairs" for whatever I currently had in my hand)*

Answer (score 2):

My American father has used this word all my life.  He would pronounce it more like "Leb-in-dy seven" so as to emphasize that it was a fake number.  He would always use it when someone asked him how old he was, or if he was describing how much effort he put into something he didn't want to do. "I must have scooped eleventy seven dog poops..." -- something like that

His grandfather was a southern American born cowboy type who ran farms and bred horses, and his great-grandfather was English.  He definitely learned this phrase from his side of the family.